# Connect Python to SharePoint List

Tags: python-3.x, sharepoint

I am trying to access a SharePoint List with OAuth2 security and am experiencing issues with gaining access.

Error:

```
Cannot get security assertion for user [user]@[company].com from federation-sts.[company].com/adfs/services/trust/2005/… 
An error occurred while retrieving auth cookies from ts.[company].com/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0
```

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext

url = 'https://company.sharepoint.com'
username = 'user123@company.com'
password = 'password'
listname = 'Test List'


ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
   ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)
   web = ctx.web
   sp_list = ctx.web.lists.get_by_title(listname)
   items = sp_list.get_items()
   ctx.load(items)
   ctx.execute_query()

else:
   print(ctx_auth.get_last_error())
```

Try #2 with SharePlum:

```
from shareplum import Site
from shareplum import Office365

authcookie = Office365('https://ts.company.com', username='user', password='pw').GetCookies()
site = Site('https://ts.company.com/sites/SiteName/', authcookie=authcookie)
```

SharePlum error (I know my credentials are correct)

```
Exception: ('Error authenticating against Office 365. Error from Office 365:', 'AADSTS50126: Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password.
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with below code on my SPO environment, it works well:

```html
tenant_url= "https://abc.sharepoint.com"
site_url="https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/A"
listname = 'Test List'

ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(tenant_url)


if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user("x@abc.onmicrosoft.com","xxxx"):
   ctx = ClientContext(site_url, ctx_auth)
   web = ctx.web
   sp_list = ctx.web.lists.get_by_title('kkkk')
   items = sp_list.get_items()
   ctx.load(items)
   ctx.execute_query()

   print(items)

else:
   print(ctx_auth.get_last_error())
```

Could you please confirm that the username/password is correct? And You can also have a try another python library for Sp connection:

- [SharePlum: Python + SharePoint](https://shareplum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Error: Cannot get security assertion for user [user]@[company].com from https://federation-sts.[company].com/adfs/services/trust/2005/usernamemixed
An error occurred while retrieving auth cookies from https://ts.[company].com/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: Confirmed that my credentials are accurate